# The most safe user login system

Tags: php, security, hash, system, crypt

I am developing website and I am doing my best to ensure that I have a good security system. I am going to tell you what I have done and I have also another question about this system.

1) I am using sha512 method to hash password.salt and save it in database

2) my salt is generating randomly and every salt is unique, I am using this methods (developed in Yii framework)

```
class Random extends CApplicationComponent
{
    public static function intRandom($min, $max) 
    {
        $bits = '';

        $diff = $max-$min;
        $bytes = ceil($diff/256);


        $fp = @fopen('/dev/urandom','rb');
        if ($fp !== FALSE) {
            $bits .= @fread($fp,$bytes);
            @fclose($fp);
        }
        $bitlength = strlen($bits);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $bitlength; $i++) {
            $int =  1+(ord($bits[$i]) % (($max-$min)+1));
        }
        return $int;
    }

    public static function strRandom($length) {
        $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_-+=|]}[{;:?.,></";   

        $size = strlen( $chars );
        for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
            $str .= $chars[ self::intRandom(0, strlen($chars)-1) ];
        }

        return $str;
    }
}
```

3) after user loges in I am generating new salt and hashing password.new_salt (of course every salt must be unique)

```
        while ($record2 !== null){
            $salt = Random::strRandom(32);
            $record2 = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('salt'=>$salt));
        }
        $record->salt = $salt;
        $record->password = hash('sha512', $this->password.$salt);
        $record->save;
```

4) now it is time to save salt in database, and I am using Rijndael two way crypting method for it. mc_key is located in php file and every month I am replacing it.

```
function mc_encrypt($encrypt, $mc_key) {
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $passcrypt = trim(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $mc_key, trim($encrypt), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    $encode = base64_encode($passcrypt);
    return $encode;
}

// Decrypt Function
function mc_decrypt($decrypt, $mc_key) {
    $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $mc_key, trim($decoded), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    return $decrypted;
}
```

So, What do you think? Is it enough or should I use something more?

I think, I made nightmare for hacker, or I am just another stupid programmer who is trying to create another bicycle.

Comment: I think this is more appropriate on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as there doesn't seem to be a problem and you're looking more for a critique.

Comment: You should have gotten a dog.

Comment: The **safest** user login system is Google OAuth with 2-step verification.

Comment: One issue is that plain SHA512 is fast. You should use a slower method, such as bcrypt.

Comment: I am sorry, I just didn't know about Code Review. And "cillosis" no, I don't have a dog, I don't need it (Kravmaga)

Comment: "CodeInChaos" yes I know but bCrypt is not supported in 1and1.com

Comment: @user1228636: You should switch to a decent host.

Comment: That random number generator has some serious problems.  If any of the calls fail (for example, due to permissions, chroot, or being on windows), it will return nothing (`0`)...  Not to mention the way it gets the numbers (modulus) is not secure at all.  Plus, it has bugs (int is overwritten each byte instead of shifted)... That's not good at all...  Instead, use a vetted random number generator, perhaps something like [CryptLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-CryptLib) specifically [Strings Example](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-CryptLib/blob/master/examples/Random/strings.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that plain SHA512 is fast. You should use a slower method, such as bcrypt

---

And `intRandom` *sucks*. If I understand it correctly

1. it fails silently when `/dev/urandom` is absent, instead of dying loudly.
2. The logic for `$max-$min>=256` looks completely broken.
3. `$min != 1` is broken
4. Its return values are not uniform

Comment: What you suggest? or is there some extentions that generates really random strings?

Comment: @user1228636 Using `/deb/urandom` is a good idea in principle. You just need to turn the bytes into an int correctly, and you need to `die()` if it can't be opened/read. But since I'm no php programmer, I don't know any ready made functions for this.

Answer (score -1):

if you are looking for a encryption algorithm you might want to check out blowfish
[CRYPT_BLOWFISH flag in the crypt package[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

Comment: Blowfish as I know is supported after php 5.3 but in my case, it is not supported, I am using php 5.1 and I am unable to change it

Comment: @user1228636: You're trying to be secure?  On 5.1?  HUH?  Upgrade first.  Then worry about it.  Otherwise it's like you're trying to put a bandaid on a gunshot wound...

Comment: blowfish it a block cipher, you mean bcrypt.

Comment: I am using 1and1.com and I am unable to use blowfish, so...